# css align elements to the right

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div in which I have a slider and a text field like:

```
<div>
    <!-- my slider -->
    <!-- my text field -->
</div>
```

As you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rW24a/6/

How do I align the slider to the right of my div so that its right side is on the same level as the right side of my textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.slider
{
    float: right;
}
textarea
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rW24a/9/)